# Javascript: what is this javascript feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading a react sample project. Here is the reducer code:

```
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT';
export const COUNTER_DOUBLE_ASYNC = 'COUNTER_DOUBLE_ASYNC';

// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [COUNTER_INCREMENT]    : (state, action) => state + action.payload,
  [COUNTER_DOUBLE_ASYNC] : (state, action) => state * 2,
};
```

I don't know what does `ACTION_HANDLERS` means. What is this javascript's feature?

Thanks

Comment: `ACTION_HANDLERS` is just a usual, uppercase identifier name used for a constant declaration here. There's no special, hidden meaning assigned to it. Look at the part of the code where it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACTION_HANDLERS is just a javascript object with [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets [], that will be computed as the property name. This is
>   symmetrical to the bracket notation of the property accessor syntax,
>   which you might have used to read and set properties already

For each action type, it has a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_HANDLERS is a constant variable declared using the `const` keyword. A constant is like a regular variable except that's it's value cannot be reassigned.

ACTION_HANDLERS in this case is an object that contains handler functions